# xpath does't work when using template

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Does someone know why xpath does not work? When I use "LG", not template with %s everything works fine.

```
public static void check(){
    String path="\"//span[@class='schema-filter__checkbox-text' and text()='%s']\"";
    String way = String.format(path, "LG");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(way); - not working
}
```

Comment: Without the XML file you are parsing, it is impossible to tell why it "doesn't work".

Comment: public static void check(){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[@class='schema-filter__checkbox-text' and text()='LG']); 
}  in this case everything works.

Comment: remove both \" from the template. If it still doesn't work just print the formatted result and compare it with the selector that works.

Comment: xpath that works is "//span[@class='schema-filter__checkbox-text' and text()='LG']". If println(way) I have exactly the same string, but with  driver.findElement(By.xpath(way) doesn't work and I wonder WHY?

Comment: Because you are/were surrounding the xpath with literal double quotes, as @Cyril explained.

Answer (score 0):

The method didnt work because I set incorrect property.
public class Page{
    static WebDriver driver;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\....\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();    - I set WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()  in the beginning.
```

.....
.....
}

and also '\' from the template should be removed.

```
public static void f(){
    String path="//span[@class='schema-filter__checkbox-text' and text()='%s']";
    String way = String.format(path, "LG");
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(way)).getText());
}
```